# How can I highlight spaces with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, highlighting

I have an input textfield that has segmented chinese words(usually they are all squashed together).
I want to highlight the space between the words, on the fly（So in other words if i type a space between 你好 the space between the characters would be red）
When I submit the text however I want to only submit the chinese with the spacing, no html or highlighting. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can apply "styling" on the text box itself. You can probably use a "preview" div (just like stackoverflow) and highlight the spaces there, using simple css.

Answer (score 0):

As @egarcia said, you can't highlight spaces in textfiled, you might want to use a rich text editor. To highlight, you might be interested in:

- [jQuery Highlight Plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html)